# How to convert a string that already looks like a list into a list?

Tags: python

I have a string that already looks like a list:

```
activeStateString = "['11', '20', '0']"
```

And I would like to define this as a list in Python. I know that I can start to filter and break it apart and rebuild a new list but then I have to go into loops etc. Is there a way in Python to promote that string from a "string" to a list straight away? So once it is converted:

```
activeStateString -> activeStateList
```

I get:

```
11
```

for:

```
print activeStateList[0]
```

Thanks

(Python 2.6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to interpret strings containing Python literals:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("['11', '20', '0']")
['11', '20', '0']
```

This is safer that using `eval()` as it will refuse to interpret anything that is *not* a literal value:

```
>>> eval("__import__('sys').version")
'2.7.5 (default, Oct 28 2013, 20:45:48) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)]'
>>> ast.literal_eval("__import__('sys').version")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the difference to `eval`.

Comment: Thanks! That should work!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "['11', '20', '0']"
>>> lst = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> lst
['11', '20', '0']
```

Use `int()` with `map` or a list comprehension if you want to convert the list items to integers:

```
>>> map(int, lst)
[11, 20, 0]
```

Help on `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> help(ast.literal_eval)
Help on function literal_eval in module ast:

literal_eval(node_or_string)
    Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
    expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
    Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
    and None.
```